# Langchain gpt-3.5-turbo models reads files - problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, langchain

I am making really simple (and for fun) LangChain project.

A model can read PDF file and I can then ask him questions about specific PDF file.

Everything works fine (**this is working example**)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import ElasticVectorSearch, Pinecone, Weaviate, FAISS

from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

reader = PdfReader('./2023_GPT4All_Technical_Report.pdf')

raw_text = ''
for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    text = page.extract_text()
    if text:
        raw_text += text

raw_text[:100]

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(        
    separator = "\n",
    chunk_size = 1000,
    chunk_overlap  = 200,
    length_function = len,
)
texts = text_splitter.split_text(raw_text)

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model='gpt-3.5-turbo')
docsearch = FAISS.from_texts(texts, embeddings)

chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")

query = "Who is the author of the book?"
docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
res = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query)

print(res)
```

**What do I see as a problem:**

If I ask a some simple question like what is 2+2 he doesn't know.. How did I lost all the knowledge of a model? Is there a workaround that model has existing knowledge and I just add a knowledge of a specific pdf file?

Thanks to everyone for asnwers and I hope a good conversion will start from my question..

Also a suggestios would be awesome!

Comment: I encountered something similar, the retrieval chain prompts are tuned to have the model try to answer from what it retrieved, which is good as it helps avoid hallucinations. But I also wanted to find a way to have the model blend its general knowledge with retrieval just for what it doesn't know. I haven't found the solution yet, I am guessing maybe inserting an extra layer of agent so it can first ask itself "do I need to look this up?" or something

Comment: I hope we would find a solution soon, haha. We can share ideas to each other and the code if you want. I can give you my twitter/fb/linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

You are using load_qa_chain which is specifically designed to perform question answering over the document data you provide as input.
Source link: https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/use_cases/question_answering.html

One way to check the efficacy of the function and the model can be to upload a document which has 2+2=4 as text and then check if the model is able to pick it up.

If you want to do general calculations on top of the LLM, create a separate calculation function and call is using agents in the chain as shown here:
https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/agents.html

Answer (score 0):

chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff")

indeed ， you use text-davinci-003 default.